# C bsearch causing segmentation fault

Tags: c, bsearch

I have the function call userInteractive(*anangramInfo) which pass in the pointer of struct anangramInfo and this struct contains the pointer "anagramPointer" to a actual anagrams.
So, i get the stdin from the user. then use that as a key of bsearch to find the pointer thoese anagram has the same anangram.sorted. then move the pointer to left until the key is not matching the anagram.sorted, then move back to the right printf the anagram.word until the anagram.sorted is not match. But it causing me the segmentation problems

```
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "anagrams.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define SIZE 80

//struct
struct anagram {
    char word[SIZE];
    char sorted[SIZE];
};

struct anagramInfo {
    struct anagram *anagramPtr;
    int             numOfAnagrams;
};



/* qsort struct comparision function (product C-string field) */ 
int sortedMemberCompare( const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2 )
{ 
    struct anagram *ia = (struct anagram *)ptr1;
    struct anagram *ib = (struct anagram *)ptr2;

    return strcmp(ia->sorted, ib->sorted);
    /* strcmp functions works exactly as expected from
    comparison function */ 
}

void userInteractive( struct anagramInfo *anagramInfoPtr ){

    struct anagram a;
    char data[SIZE];
    char *pos;

    printf("Enter a word to search for anagrams [^D to exit]:\n");
    fgets(data, SIZE, stdin);

    //get ripe of the '\n'
    pos=strchr(data, '\n');
    *pos = '\0';

    strncpy(a.word,data,sizeof(data));

    //lowercase word
    int i;
    for(i=0;data[i] != '\0';i++)
      {
        data[i]=(char)tolower(data[i]);
      }

    /* sort array using qsort functions */ 
    qsort(data,strlen(data), 1, charCompare);

    strncpy(a.sorted,data,sizeof(data));

    //struct pointer to the elements
    struct anagram *ptr= (struct anagram *)bsearch(a.sorted,anagramInfoPtr-> anagramPtr ->sorted,anagramInfoPtr-> numOfAnagrams,sizeof(struct anagram),sortedMemberCompare);

    printf(ptr->word);

    while(strncmp(ptr ->sorted,a.sorted,sizeof(a.sorted))==0) {
        ptr--;
    }

    while(strncmp(ptr ->sorted,a.sorted,sizeof(a.sorted))==0) {
        printf(ptr ->word);
        printf(" ");
        ptr++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe some of the strings happen to be 80 chars long? ->> please read the manual pages for strncpy()

Comment: How do you initialize the anagramInfo struct?

Comment: i initialize it in the main code

Comment: @maerics Why would this be moved to programmers.se? This is a question about a specific programming implementation issue, it is precisely on topic for StackOverflow and not for programmers.se.

Comment: @BrianCampbell: you're right - i misread this question as being about the binary search algorithm itself instead of this particular implementation.

Comment: The struct anagram has the both anagram.word and anagram.sorted with SIZE OF 80.

Comment: `strlen(some char array)` is not the same as `sizeof(some char array)`.

Comment: Don't put spaces around either the `.` or the `->` operators; they bind more tightly than any others (or as tightly).  Do put spaces after commas.  Do check the return value from `fgets()` and do not continue if it reports failure.  Do not print the return value from `bsearch()` without checking that `bsearch()` found something.  You've not provided a SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) so the code can be made to compile and it runs but runs foul of the error checking, but can't be made to show your problem because it isn't all the code we need.

Comment: `*pos = '\0';` <- if `fgets` didn't get to store an '\n', that's going to be ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Your oversight is that `bsearch` *is not searching on a contiguous array*; it is not even searching in the right place, since you are searching for *sorted strings*, but you ought to search for *sorted members of anagrams*:

```
struct anagram *ptr = (struct anagram *)bsearch(&a,
            anagramInfoPtr-> anagramPtr,
            anagramInfoPtr-> numOfAnagrams,
            sizeof(struct anagram),
            sortedMemberCompare);
```

Then, when `bsearch` fails and returns `NULL`, you do not check that `ptr` is `NULL` and use it; hence the segfault. (You also do not check `NULL` at the Ctrl-D).

## Test

This is a modified version - I added back the `charCompare` function and whipped up a `main()` with five fixed strings in order to make it work, after a fashion.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define SIZE 80

//struct
struct anagram {
    char word[SIZE];
    char sorted[SIZE];
};

struct anagramInfo {
    struct anagram *anagramPtr;
    int             numOfAnagrams;
};

/* qsort struct comparision function (product C-string field) */
int sortedMemberCompare( const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2 )
{
    struct anagram *ia = (struct anagram *)ptr1;
    struct anagram *ib = (struct anagram *)ptr2;

    return strcmp(ia->sorted, ib->sorted);
    /* strcmp functions works exactly as expected from
    comparison function */
}

int charCompare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
        const char *aa = a, *bb = b;
        if (*aa < *bb)
                return -1;
        if (*aa == *bb)
                return 0;
        return 1;
}

void userInteractive( struct anagramInfo *anagramInfoPtr ){

    struct anagram a;
    char data[SIZE];
    char *pos;

    printf("Enter a word to search for anagrams [^D to exit]:\n");
    fgets(data, SIZE, stdin);

    //get ripe of the '\n'
    pos=strchr(data, '\n'); // In Windows this might be a "\r" maybe?
    if (NULL == pos)
       exit(0);

    *pos = '\0';

    strncpy(a.word,data,sizeof(data));

    //lowercase word
    int i;
    for(i=0;data[i] != '\0';i++)
    {
        data[i]=(char)tolower(data[i]);
    }

    /* sort array using qsort functions */
    qsort(data, strlen(data), 1, charCompare);
    strncpy(a.sorted,data,sizeof(data));

    //struct pointer to the elements
    struct anagram *ptr = (struct anagram *)bsearch(&a,
                anagramInfoPtr-> anagramPtr,
                anagramInfoPtr-> numOfAnagrams,
                sizeof(struct anagram),
                sortedMemberCompare);

    // You must check that ptr is not NULL.
    if (NULL == ptr)
    {
        printf("Not found\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Found: %s\n", ptr->word);

    /* Here there is a subtle error. If you find the FIRST item of the list,
       this code will position itself BEFORE THE BEGINNING of the list, and
       run a strncmp() against who knows what. Other segfault lurking! */

    while(ptr > anagramInfoPtr -> anagramPtr && strncmp(ptr ->sorted,a.sorted,strlen(a.sorted))==0) {
        ptr--;
    }

    // while(strncmp(ptr ->sorted,a.sorted,sizeof(a.sorted))==0) {
    //    ptr--;
    //}

    // Here too you should check you do not pass max number of anagrams,
    // if you hit the last item of the lot.
    while(strncmp(ptr ->sorted,a.sorted,sizeof(a.sorted))==0) {
        printf(ptr ->word);
        printf(" ");
        ptr++;
    }

}

int main()
{
        int i;
        struct anagramInfo *root;

        root = malloc(sizeof(struct anagramInfo));

        root->numOfAnagrams     = 5;
        root->anagramPtr        = malloc(root->numOfAnagrams * sizeof(struct anagram));

        strcpy(root->anagramPtr[0].word, "oriental");
        strcpy(root->anagramPtr[1].word, "teaching");
        strcpy(root->anagramPtr[2].word, "senator");
        strcpy(root->anagramPtr[3].word, "admirer");
        strcpy(root->anagramPtr[4].word, "rescued");

        for (i = 0; i < root->numOfAnagrams; i++)
        {
            int j;
            for (j = 0; root->anagramPtr[i].word[j]; j++)
               root->anagramPtr[i].word[j] = tolower(root->anagramPtr[i].word[j]);
            strcpy(root->anagramPtr[i].sorted, root->anagramPtr[i].word);
            qsort(root->anagramPtr[i].sorted, strlen(root->anagramPtr[i].sorted), 1, charCompare);
        }
        qsort(root-> anagramPtr, root-> numOfAnagrams, sizeof(struct anagram), sortedMemberCompare);
        for (;;)
            userInteractive(root);
    }
```

## Run

```
$ gcc -W -Wall -o anagram anagram.c
$ ./anagram
Enter a word to search for anagrams [^D to exit]:
treason
Found: senator

Enter a word to search for anagrams [^D to exit]:
cheating
Found: teaching

Enter a word to search for anagrams [^D to exit]:
relation
Found: oriental

Enter a word to search for anagrams [^D to exit]:

$
```